# any simple method to do integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-2}^{x^{2}-2x}e^{t}.e^{t^2} dt = ?$$

What i did is...
on rewriting it , $$\int_{-2}^{x^{2}-2x}e^{t+t^2} dt=\frac{e^{t+t^2}}{t^2/2+t^3/3}  $$ and then substituting limits is very long process

Is there any simple method for this?

someone please explain me how to do this integration just $\int e^{t}.e^{t^2} dt $

Comment: What you did is wrong. Integration does not work like that... (What would be the integral of $e^t$ with your method?)

Comment: integral of $e^t$ is $e^t$

Comment: That is the right answer, but what you did suggested otherwise ($2e^t/t^2$). What I'm saying is that the chain rule does not work for integration this way. Try to integrate $\sin(t^2)$ (if you can) and differentiate the result.

Comment: i couldn't do it

Comment: Does the problem ask you to take the derivative (w.r.t. $x$) of that integral?

Comment: no its asked w.r.t 't'.forget about x and find only the integral e^(t+t^2)

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid that what you did is wrong : you are not integrating a polynomial expression. Just for your curiosity,$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\frac{e^{t+t^2}}{t^2/2+t^3/3}\Big)=\frac{6 e^{t+t^2} (t+2) \left(4 t^2-3\right)}{t^3 (2 t+3)^2} \neq e^{t+t^2}$$

To compute $$I=\int e^{t}.e^{t^2} dt=\int e^{t^2+t} dt$$ first complete the square for the exponent and perform a change of variable $y=t+\frac{1}{2}$ and you will arrive to $$I=e^{-\frac{1}{4}} \int e^{y^2} dy$$ where appears a classical antiderivative. So, back to $t$, $$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt[4]{e}}$$

Now, you could go for the integral.